# +-12 V from two 12 V DC PSU

Tags: power-supply, dc

I'm having two of those [PSU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XJVYDDW). How can I make +-12 V DC from those units? Any schematic you can share?

Comment: Please provide pdf data sheet links for the devices.

Comment: @nanash1 It does not have +12V and -12V output. It just has a single 12V output, with a supply terminals and return terminals.

Comment: Just connect PSU output to load, + to +, - to-.

Comment: @justme It has +V and -V which is supposedly +12 and-12.

Comment: @Justme You're right. I misread the labels. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @user263983 If you insist there are +12V and -12V outputs, that's 24V, and where is the 0V output then, to actually use +12V or -12V only? It simply has a positive terminal and negative terminal for 12V output. Just like a 12V car battery does.

Comment: @justme power supply does not have 0V. It is choise of user. You can make +12V as 0 and it will be -12V PSU.

Comment: @user263983 Yes, so first you said the supply has +12V and -12V outputs, now you are saying it doesn't?

Comment: @@justme I said the 0 Volt is relative point and can be chosen by user. Output of single PSU has + and -. "0" is abstract number, it does not exist in nature.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the schematic to obtain + 12 V & - 12V using two 12 V DC power supplies.

[image]

It is to be ensured that the output terminals are isolated from the chassis.

Comment: Just be sure that the `-` terminal is isolated from `PE`, which is not always the case. I agree the linked PSU probably is, but can't be sure as it doesn't explicitly state that.

Comment: @TomCarpenter - Hi Tom, Many thanks for pointing it out. My answer has been edited accordingly.

Comment: As there is no info on the power supply output being isolated or earthed, the schematics on the answer may either work or blow up the other supply.